# ASP.NET Core : create JWT token with invalid date

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect

I'm trying to get an JWT token:

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
    var exp = await context.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");
    var expires = DateTime.Parse(exp);

    if (expires > DateTime.Now)
    {
        return await context.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
    }

    return await GetRefreshedAccessToken();
}
```

But when I put the JWT string that was accepted in the token in https://token.dev/

I get invalid date on "auth_time" - why and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: When you check the same token on jwt.io, the auth_time is interpreted correctly. And when the token was accepted as you mentioned, it doesn't seem to be a real problem. Maybe tell the people who made that website about the problem.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the standard timestamp format is the numerical format in seconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC as seen here on the exp and iat timestamps.  But IMHO the standard format does not apply to non-standard claims like auth_time. Maybe on that website they implemented a rule that just generally checks the date format.

Answer (score 0):

In JWT, the fields about time are in `Unix Timestamp` format.

[image]

#### You need to convert your time to this format.

```
[HttpGet("GetUnixTimeStamp")]
public string GetAccessToken()
{
    string dateStart = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz");
    DateTime Start = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStart, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    long unixStart = (long)Start
        .ToUniversalTime()
        .Subtract(DateTime.UnixEpoch)
        .TotalSeconds;
    return unixStart.ToString();
}
```

[image]